# Radio Input check or uncheck

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a form that contains some Checkboxes and one Radio.

The problem is that all the Checkboxes are controlled by a jQuery code to change the style.

Every checkbox in that form will be styled because the jQuery code.

But I was in need to have only one checkbox not styled. So I had to use a Radio.

I have only one Radio, and I need to find a function to check/uncheck it as it was a normal checkbox.

Is this possible? I run jQuery 1.3.2

Comment: Can you show us your code?  Radios and Checkboxes are toggled in exactly the same way.

Comment: can you provide some `//sample code`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is phrased in a very confusing way but I think you are asking how, from javascript, to set whether a radiobutton is checked or not.

You can set  `myRadioButton.checked = false;`  or `myRadioButton.checked = true;`

Comment: You are near to what I am looking for. How do I do this? If the radiobutton is checked, onclick uncheck it and vice versa?

Comment: toggling a boolean value is trivial:  myRadioButton.checked = !myRadioButton.checked;

Answer (score 4):

This is an abuse of radio buttons and subverts their purpose. Instead of breaking the user interface to fit your needs, simply add in some conditional logical to exempt your special checkbox from the styling rules. In pseudo-code:

```
if (checkbox.name != 'exempt me') {
    apply_style();
} else {
    do_something_special();
}
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I am using a jQuery code not made by me. So I do not really know how to modify that code. And also I made my question simpler, but that is not so simple. I just need to know how to check/uncheck a radio button. Nothing else.

Comment: @diego: `$('#yourradiobutton').attr('checked', false);` But again, this is breaking user interface conventions. In real world terms, you're trying to force a door knob to control a ceiling lamp. Might make sense to you, but is going to confuse everyone else.

Comment: Sorry but I am still confused. As I see this code will only uncheck the radio button. But what happen if the user wants that checked? How do I fire an onclick event on it? Sorry but as you may understand I am not a javascript expert...

Comment: `$('#yourradiobutton').click(function() { this.checked = !this.checked; });` will just toggle the radio button. And yet again, this is a BAD design decision.